# SQL : Weird query performance after "select into" a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I experience a weird situation as below:

I have a huge table in a database named "Table1".
Then, i duplicate exact the same table with following code.

`Select *
into Table2
from Table1`

After that,
I find that the query performance is dramatically difference.

`Select count (distinct ID)
from Table1`
takes almost 2 minutes to complete. (Old table)

Meanwhile,
`Select count (distinct ID) 
from Table2`
takes just about 10 secs to complete (New table)

By the way, i find that the data had been reorder in newtable after "select into".
Besides, There was a column added into Table1 (Old table) before "select into" the new table
(which is Alter a table , add col1 as col2.)

So, how does this happen?

> *(NB: The original version of the question stated that the new table was the slow one. This was an error. Also, it didn't mention about the data manipulation on Table1)*

---

#### Responses to requests for more information

This is the outcome from Sebastian's code.

```
SELECT  QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) tbl,
        s.name stats_name,
        cols.cols,
        t.create_date table_date,
        STATS_DATE(s.object_id, s.stats_id) AS statistics_date,
        s.auto_created,
        s.user_created,
        s.no_recompute,
        s.has_filter,
        s.filter_definition
FROM    sys.tables t
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.stats s
        ON s.object_id = t.object_id
OUTER APPLY (
              SELECT  STUFF((SELECT ',' + c.name
                             FROM   sys.stats_columns sc
                             JOIN   sys.columns c
                                    ON sc.column_id = c.column_id
                                       AND sc.object_id = c.object_id
                             WHERE  sc.object_id = s.object_id
                                    AND sc.stats_id = s.stats_id
                             ORDER BY sc.stats_column_id
                      FOR   XML PATH(''),
                                TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') cols
            ) cols
--Update Table Name(s) here:      
WHERE   t.OBJECT_ID IN ( OBJECT_ID('[Sales].[SpecialOffer]'),
        OBJECT_ID('[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]') );
```

and

```
SELECT  name,
        compatibility_level,
        is_auto_close_on,
        is_auto_shrink_on,
        state_desc,
        is_auto_create_stats_on,
        is_auto_update_stats_on,
        is_auto_update_stats_async_on
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id = DB_ID();
```

Actually , I copy the new table to another database. 
And the table name is actually named ID2000

The top image is refer to "Table1" (Database 1)
the bottom image is refer to "Table2" (Database 2)

[image: "Table1"]

[image: "Table2"]

---

Well, since the XML code is too long, Here is the alternative printout which followed Hamlet's advice.
I use
`SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON GO`
instead of pasting all XML code. I hope it help.

The red colour represent the "Table 1" plan , and black colour represent "Table 2".
The text in the image is a-bit small, but zoom in by increase this page size will simply enlarge it.

Thank you very much!!
[image: Figure 1]

---

The result of `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),object_id('YourTable'),NULL,NULL,'Detaile‌​d')`.

Indeed, there is a huge different between two tables. 
Same, the red colour refer to "Table 1", and the another refer to "Table 2"

This problem is quite annoying, its driving me crazy because i keep asking myself should i rebuild all the table or not. :(
[image]

Actually its quite bizarre, Note that the record_count is different. 
However, when i recheck with 
`select COUNT (ID) from id2000` , (i.e. Calculate total data rows on this table)
Both results are 2324798, which is record_count of Table_2

Moreover, "Table2" was created by "select * into" statement, i suppose both should be same, yet now i am confused.

[image]
The above table is the outcome from the code (Running stat) from Sebastian code

---

The result of `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),object_id('YourTable'),NULL,NULL,'Detaile‌​d')`.

Indeed, there is a huge different between two tables. 
Same, the red colour refer to "Table 1", and the another refer to "Table 2"

This problem is quite annoying, its driving me crazy because i keep asking myself should i rebuild all the table or not. :(
[image]

Actually its quite bizarre, Note that the record_count is different. 
However, when i recheck with 
`select COUNT (ID) from id2000` , (i.e. Calculate total data rows on this table)
Both results are 2324798, which is record_count of Table_2

Moreover, "Table2" was created by "select * into" statement, i suppose both should be same, yet now i am confused.

Comment: do you have indexes in table1 and they don't exist in table2 ?

Comment: I checked , there are no indexes on both tables. :(

Comment: do you have any constraints in table1?

Comment: Nop :( ,  the Table1 is just a very simple table, imported from a txt file with regular way, and without doing any further action. The only thing i had modified is add a column with a little calculation. 

ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD age
AS 2012-birthyear

Comment: Checked again. No any primary key, foreign key, index, Constraints set...

Comment: Please post the XML for the actual execution plans for both versions.

Comment: @All please only post answers in the answer section (or if posting diagnostic queries too long for comments at least clean them up when more information is forthcoming and they are obsolete) though even those "ought" to be not supplied as an answer but put on pastebin or somewhere.

Comment: I had try to modify this thread and moving useful information on this thread. But why i am not able to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now that we have sorted out that the old table was the slow one and not the new one, everything points to the extremely high amount of forwarded records being the culprit.

To remove the forwarded records you can use this query:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2 REBUILD;
```

Adding a column to a heap will most likely cause every row to move frequently causing a very high amount of forwarded records. The column `forwarded_records_count` returned by the `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` DMV shows the number of forwards - almost all rows in your case.

A `SELECT * INTO` does not copy the forwarding pointers but instead reorganizes it. Hence the performance difference you did see.

While we are talking about forwards, in most cases it is a very good idea to have a clustered index on the table. That avoids issues like this.

In your case the ID column seems to be a candidate for a clustered primary key (if it is unique), but I would need to know more about the model to give you a recommendation here.

Comment: +1 Agree entirely. If you want your interim diagnostic queries preserved you should likely incorporate them into this answer though as they run the risk of being deleted as not an answer at the moment though.

Comment: Yeah, I agree to what you said. Add cluster index is a good idea and i am planning to do that in the future. Clustered PK is even a better option here but i have to plan it in details in the future. In fact, Due to large amount of tables, I am still doing data cleaning. Again, I think your answer is excellent and this problem is considered solved.

Comment: I sincerely thank Sebastian, Martin and the others for their help. Also the moderator who maintained this page while i being a noob in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Another one to try: Please run this and post text as well as query results. As always make sure to replace Table1 and Table2 with the real names. You also need to replace the database names in this case.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
GO
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM DB1.dbo.Table1
GO
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM DB2.dbo.Table2
GO
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM DB1.dbo.Table1
GO
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM DB2.dbo.Table2
GO
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM DB1.dbo.Table1
GO
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM DB2.dbo.Table2
GO
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(DB_ID('DB1'),OBJECT_ID('DB1.dbo.Table1'),NULL,NULL);
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(DB_ID('DB2'),OBJECT_ID('DB2.dbo.Table2'),NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: OK, i will post this with along with the previous XML section.

Comment: @YinYeeLeong - BTW please edit your question to supply the results rather than add it as another answer.

Comment: Do you still want the XML section? since we dont think the problem can be discovered from there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is caused by out of date statistics. But we need a little more information about your environment. Could you run these two queries and post the results? Make sure you use the names of your two tables instead of the two supplied.

```
SELECT  QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) tbl,
        s.name stats_name,
        cols.cols,
        t.create_date table_date,
        STATS_DATE(s.object_id, s.stats_id) AS statistics_date,
        s.auto_created,
        s.user_created,
        s.no_recompute,
        s.has_filter,
        s.filter_definition
FROM    sys.tables t
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.stats s
        ON s.object_id = t.object_id
OUTER APPLY (
              SELECT  STUFF((SELECT ',' + c.name
                             FROM   sys.stats_columns sc
                             JOIN   sys.columns c
                                    ON sc.column_id = c.column_id
                                       AND sc.object_id = c.object_id
                             WHERE  sc.object_id = s.object_id
                                    AND sc.stats_id = s.stats_id
                             ORDER BY sc.stats_column_id
                      FOR   XML PATH(''),
                                TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') cols
            ) cols
--Update Table Name(s) here:      
WHERE   t.OBJECT_ID IN ( OBJECT_ID('[Sales].[SpecialOffer]'),
        OBJECT_ID('[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]') );
```

and

```
SELECT  name,
        compatibility_level,
        is_auto_close_on,
        is_auto_shrink_on,
        state_desc,
        is_auto_create_stats_on,
        is_auto_update_stats_on,
        is_auto_update_stats_async_on
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id = DB_ID();
```

Comment: Have moved this query into the question so don't think this answer serves any purpose any more?

Comment: @MartinSmith, while this query did not provide the hoped for answer it is an important step in the process of solving this problem. So I would no appreciate you deleting it.

Comment: I also do not appreciate all the down-votes without a comment.

Comment: So should i take any action such as hide this anwser? I am new user on this forum and please guide me :)

Comment: @SebastianMeine - Stack Overflow is a question and answer site not a forum. Answers should be full answers to the question. If you think this is an important step then by all means incorporate it into one full complete coherent answer. Having random queries scattered around in separate answers is just noise and not the way stack overflow works.

Comment: I didn't do that vote... :( . And conversely, i appreciate any kind of reply.

Comment: @SebastianMeine alot of folks will use the chat rooms to do the back-and-forth discussion. It is alot easier than doing it through the comments in an answer.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21467/questions-chat